# Can Windows Fax and Scan use an HP OfficeJet for faxes?

Tags: windows-7, fax, hp-officejet

I have an HP OfficeJet 5610 AIO printer/scanner/fax, and I'm running Windows 7 without HP custom drivers for the printer. Printing and scanning works fine, but is it possible to use the built-in Windows Fax and Scan for sending faxes with the printer instead of installing the horrible HP fax software?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7hardware/thread/df1b389a-1929-41a8-a19f-a748a5041360), it is not supported at all:

> Fax and Scan cannot use an AIO device (HP or otherwise) to send faxes nor will it work with a networked scanner.  It can only send faxes through an analog fax/data modem [...]